# How to update UI from work manager on relaunch of app

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-workmanager

I am using **WorkManager** in my app to upload big videos to server. First I make chunks of video file and then upload through work manager. I need to show the progress of upload on UI, and Work manager is launched from my **viewmodel**. I am using single activity with **jetpack compose**, and my viewmodel is scoped to activity. When app is alive everything works fine, but if its instance is cleared from memory while upload is in progress, upload continues to happen but when app relaunches, since the viewmodel instance is new, I am unable to get status of upload from work manager and update UI. Any idea how to tackle this? Any help much appreciated.
This is how I launch my WorkManager. Currently creating WM for each chunk due to some progress update issues in single WM per video.

```
  private fun uploadVideo(chunk: VideoData) {
    if (!appContext.isOnline(analyticsManager)) {
        showNoNetwork.value = true
    }

    val workManager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(appContext)
    val uploadWorkRequest: WorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadVideoWorkManager>()
        .setConstraints(
            Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()
        )
        .setInputData(
            workDataOf(
                ParamKeys.VIDEO to videoData.value?.toJsonString()
            )

        )
        .build()
    workManager.enqueue(uploadWorkRequest)
    val liveData = workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uploadWorkRequest.id)
    workInfoObserver = androidx.lifecycle.Observer { workInfo ->
        updateUploadStatus(workInfo, liveData)
    }
    liveData.observeForever(workInfoObserver!!)
}
```

**Is using broadcast receiver the only solution? or is there any other ways?**

Comment: You need to include some code

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov I am not sure which part of code will be helpful here. Can you please let me know what should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this** **[article](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/observe)**

You can send data from work manager this way:

```
fun doWork(): Result {
    var progress = 0
    setProgress(
        workDataOf("KEY" to progress)
    )

    // other code
}
```

And collect it with kotlin Flow:

```
val workProgressFlow: Flow<Int> = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        .getWorkInfosLiveData(WorkQuery.fromUniqueWorkNames("work_name"))
        .asFlow()
        .map { it.single().outputData.getInt("KEY", 0) }
```

If your work is unique it must persists data after app relaunch.

If there's something I don't understand, write down the problem in detail

Comment: thanks for your response. As you said my work manager is working fine and upload happens, but problem is with UI update. My work manager communicates with the viewmodel to update the status of UI, but here when app was killed and relaunched , the new instance of viewmodel is created for the UI and work manager callback goes to old instance. So UI doesn't get updated.

Comment: @andro-girl show me your viewmodel

Comment: @andro-girl I think the problem is how you get the data. WorkManager stores job data in its database. It is persistent and queries to it can be made anywhere. Also, what does it mean that the 'WorkManager Callback goes to old instance'? ViewModel is destroyed after app relaunch and there is no old instance at all

Comment: actually I am using WM with observeForever .code is updated above

Comment: Wait, are you using many works for uploading just a single chunk. It is completely wrong. WM is not designed for this. You need only one WM for this. You can pass chunks to Worker through repository and send asynchronously each chunk. You have many not unique works so after relaunch you unable to track them

Comment: We need to upload chunks sequentially due to server side limitations, so basically when a chunk upload is success we upload next one. But I understand your point that it should be a single WM to handle whole video upload. Due to some progress update issue from WM, did it this way.

Comment: @andro-girl what kind of issue you talking about? Maybe you can share gists

Comment: doWork or createWork methods return a Result object from WM, but as we have to do our upload() recursively to upload all chunks, we have to return the Result only if it is the last chunk and that is not possible as return statement is mandatory regardless of if-else condition

Comment: @andro-girl I need you to provide your code. I can't help with just seeing logic